# Is there a Qt/QML function to check if a shape has been clicked?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qqmlcomponent

I am trying to register a click in a QML Shape which forms a hexagon.
I know there is the

> Shape.FillContains() https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shapes-shape.html#containsMode-prop

property which I am trying to use.
But I do not know how to proceed further because I have just worked with MouseAreas before.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.15
import QtQuick.Extras 1.4

Item
{
    id: root
    property real srh //ScaleFactor
    Shape
    {
        id: rootShape
        width:  srh * (6.5 - 0.5)
        height: srh * 5.2
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        containsMode: Shape.FillContains

        ShapePath
        {
            id: myHexagon
            strokeWidth: 4
            strokeColor: "white"
            fillColor: "steelblue"

            //Path
            startX:         2 * srh;
            startY:                     0   * srh
            PathLine { x: 5   * srh; y: 0   * srh }
            PathLine { x: 6.5 * srh; y: 2.6 * srh }
            PathLine { x: 5.0 * srh; y: 5.2 * srh }
            PathLine { x: 2.0 * srh; y: 5.2 * srh }
            PathLine { x: 0.5 * srh; y: 2.6 * srh }
            PathLine { x: 2   * srh; y: 0   * srh }
        }
}
```

Does anyone know how to work with this? Something like the onClicked()-Handler would be nice.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation about `containsMode` says :

> It is useful in case you add [Qt Quick Input Handlers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickhandlers-index.html) and you want to react only when the mouse or touchpoint is fully inside the Shape.

You can use an input handler like [`TapHandler`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-taphandler.html) or [`HoverHandler`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-hoverhandler.html), they use the contains method of their parent.

```
Shape {
    id: rootShape
    width:  srh * (6.5 - 0.5)
    height: srh * 5.2
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    containsMode: Shape.FillContains

    ShapePath {
        id: myHexagon
        strokeWidth: 4
        strokeColor: "white"
        fillColor: hoverHandler.hovered ? "gold" : "steelblue"

        //Path
        startX:         2 * srh;
        startY:                     0   * srh
        PathLine { x: 5   * srh; y: 0   * srh }
        PathLine { x: 6.5 * srh; y: 2.6 * srh }
        PathLine { x: 5.0 * srh; y: 5.2 * srh }
        PathLine { x: 2.0 * srh; y: 5.2 * srh }
        PathLine { x: 0.5 * srh; y: 2.6 * srh }
        PathLine { x: 2   * srh; y: 0   * srh }
    }
    HoverHandler {
        id: hoverHandler
    }
    TapHandler {
        onTapped: print("Hexagon clicked")
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @GrecKo I was a little bit confused with the containsMode.

Comment: Do you know how to change the HoverHandler so that I can execute Code like in onTapped {... } sometehing like onHovered: {...} but I cant find something in the documentation just canceled() and grabChanged() which is not really helpful. 
The fillColor: hoverHandler.hovered ? "gold" : "steelblue" is pretty good but I need to execute a little bit more code on hovering

Comment: This works:
        HoverHandler {
            id: myHover
            onHoveredChanged:
            {
                if(hovered)
                {
  
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }

        }

Answer (score 0):

The docs you link to already seem to point to the answer. Have you tried combining `containsMode` with a `MouseArea`?

```
Shape 
{
    id: shape
    signal clicked()

    containsMode: Shape.FillContains

    MouseArea
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked:
        {
            if (shape.contains(Qt.point(mouseX, mouseY)))
            {
                shape.clicked();
            }
        }
    }
}
```